Flutter text widget set fontFamily PingFang SC will auto scale,but i dont need scale how can i fix it
Text(
 info.getSubTitle(),
 style: TextStyle(
 fontSize: 14,
 fontFamily: "PingFang SC",
 color: CityColors.light.description,
).setPingFang(),
 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
 maxLines: 1,
)

when i set fontfamily i will see text auto scale at the end of the line,
the yellow line will show error layout with text on the image
and this is my flutter version
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale
zh-Hans-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
! Error: Browsing on the local area network for chenrui. Ensure the device
is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local
area network as this Mac.
The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code
-27)
! Error: Browsing on the local area network for iPhone. Ensure the device is
unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area
network as this Mac.
The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code
-27)
[✓] Network resources

enter image description here
